# Google spreadsheets have a column limit?

Tags: google-sheets

I read that google spreadsheets have a column limit of something like 20000.
However my spreadsheet does not have any column beyond AC.

How can I add columns to my spreadsheet?? (in Excel this is automatic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert more columns in the `Insert` menu.

[image]

If you need to insert more than one column, you can highlight a number of columns and it'll prompt to insert that amount:

[image]

### High Quantity Method

If you need a huge amount of columns inserted, open a text editor, create a large quantity of `TAB` characters, and copy into Google Sheet.

Google Sheet will interpret each tab as a column so it'll quickly create new columns based on the number of tab characters you have pasted.

Answer (score 1):

You can go up to column ZZZ, which is exactly 18,278 columns following @Nelson 's process

[image]

**[EDIT:]** You can use the script below to add a specific number of columns

```
function userAddColumns() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("How many columns do you want to add?");

  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn(), result.getResponseText());

};
```

Comment: Yes, but it seems like a painfully slow process to go till zzz... no?

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternate method.

Comment: @KansaiRobot I've added a script. When you run it will prompt you how many columns you want to add.